# PHP Dynamic include based on current file path

Tags: php, dynamic, include, filenames

I want to find a method to include some files based on the current file path.. for example:

I have "website.com/templates/name1/index.php", this "index.php should be a unique file that I will use in many different directories on different depths, so I want to make the code universal so I don't need to change anything inside this file..

So if this "index.php" is located in

"**website.com**/templates/name1/index.php"

than it should include the file located here:

"**website.com/content**/templates/name1/content.php"

another example:

"**website.com**/templates/name2/index.php"

than it should include the file located here:

"**website.com/content**/templates/name2/content.php"

Also I want to overrun "*Warning: include_once() [function.include-once]: http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0*" kind of error.. because is disabled and unsafe..

Is there a way to achieve this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think you need to use **__FILE__** (it has two underscores at the start and at the end of  the name) and **DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR** constants for working with files based on the current file path.

For example:

```
<?php
  // in this var you will get the absolute file path of the current file
  $current_file_path = dirname(__FILE__);
  // with the next line we will include the 'somefile.php'
  // which based in the upper directory to the current path
  include(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'somefile.php');
```

Using **DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR** constant is more safe than using **"/"** (or **"\"**) symbols, because Windows and *nix directory separators are different and your interpretator will use proper value on the different platforms.

Answer (score 3):

You can place your includes inside conditional logic.

```
<?php   
if (isset($_GET['service'])) {
    include('subContent/serviceMenu.html');
} else if (isset($_GET['business'])) {
    include('subContent/business_menu.html');
} else if (isset($_GET['info'])) {
    include('subContent/info_menu.html');
}
else {
    include('subContent/banner.html');
}
?>
<a href="http://localhost/yourpage.php?service" />
```

Comment: Generally, code-only answers are considered poor quality. Perhaps you could provide a snippet of explanation of what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I'd just do something as simple as:

```
$dir = str_replace('website.com/','website.com/content/',__DIR__);
include "$dir/content.php";
```

And your HTTP wrapper issue doesn't seem to have anything to do with this.  What do you mean by overrun it?  You generally never want to do a remote include.

Answer (score -1):

Why not do it in the simple way:

```
dirname(__FILE__); //Current working directory
dirname(dirname(__FILE__)); //Get path to current working directory
```

And then finally

```
$include_path = $dir_path . 'file_to_include.php';
include $include_path;
```